# Make Angular Web App available offline

Tags: angularjs, offline, indexeddb, service-worker, localforage

I am struggling with some details about finding a solution to make an Angular / C# app available offline. 
My idea would be to use [upup.js](https://github.com/TalAter/UpUp) the get the business logic for the SPA in Angular available offline. upup.js uses service workers to do so. I would store the data required for the offline app using [angular-localForage](https://github.com/ocombe/angular-localForage) which uses IndexedDB and falls back to WebSQL and localStorage in case. 
The problem is, that I have to make files and images available offline too without requiring the user to visit the page they are being used on and I am worried about the maximum quotas. I could store them using either upup.js and adding those files as assets, or store them with angular-localForage as blobs. IndexedDB is supposed to be unlimited by now if I am informed correctly? I couldn't find any maximum quota for a service worker though, as the upup.js solution would use. The AppCache is deprecated, so I wouldn't use that... Or maybe I understood something completely wrong, or there is even another, better solution? Anyhow, the question is:

**TL;DR: What is the better way to store files for an AngularJS offline application: [angular-localForage](https://github.com/ocombe/angular-localForage) (IndexedDB etc.) or a Service Worker ([upup.js](https://github.com/TalAter/UpUp)) and what are the maximum quotas for each solution? Or is there an even better solution?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion Service Worker (SW) is better than tradition local storage. Plus SW can also use indexedDB.

For the implementation, it is very depending. How your app structure, what technologies of front-end being with with your angular app, what is your main goals of using SW...?

---

#### 1. Traditional JS loading, you are likely merge all the JS file in one... like `app.js` contains everything.

And you also don't care about Push Notification neither any other cool features that SW offering.

=> For this case it seem like `upup.js` suite you the best.

*NOTE* : beware that `upup.js` attempt to registering SW on it own, so it likely blocking or complexified your work on expanding feature of SW.

---

#### 2. Advanced AMD user, where almost all of your JS chopped to small pieces... like `fooCtrl.js`, `barCtrl.js`, etc...

For sure you don't want to configure like 100+ files of JS, and further more you will got a lot of html template to load.

=> In this case I will suggest you to use `sw-toolbox` . A very powerful and light weight tool made by Google. At initial if you are not familiar with SW concept yet, you will have a bit of trouble setting it up for your site (but it won't be longer than a day of you are an advanced JS developer)

After all has configured, all become so very simple. For example this is how I cache all of static content in my site.

```
self.toolbox.router.get(/(.js|.css|.png|.jpg|.json|.html)/, self.toolbox.fastest);
```

---

#### 3. You don't care about what kind of technology at front-end side. You just interest with SW.

=> Simply go for `sw-toolbox` it's a real time-saver for basic configuration. And if you want to expand the usage of SW, you can just expand it by your own will.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't need push notifications or anything fancy, just basic offline availability. The app is also fairly small, so I have JS chopped to small pieces but it's maybe 15 pieces in total so I would still opt for upup.js to save me from having to learning sw-toolbox... Thank you so much for the suggestion though!